# spark-shell cannot autocomplete when running in docker with --user

Tags: apache-spark, docker

I run spark-shell with docker. spark-shell's autocompletion works fine when I do docker run without --user, i.e. spark-shell with root.

```
$ docker run --rm -it docker-spark-image spark-shell
scala> sc.[TAB]
List of SparkContext functions ...
```

However, if I do docker run with --user. Autocompletion does not work with .[TAB].

```
$ docker run --rm -it --user 1234:100 --volume=/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro --volume=/etc/group:/etc/group:ro docker-spark-image spark-shell
```

Is there any file permission for spark-shell autocompletion to work? Thank you.